# Python input() function is skipping a line on the first input

Tags: python, input, user-input

I'am trying to make a text-adventure but i encountered a weird problem that I can't solve. I dont know what I've changed because I know it worked at some point but the startinput doesn't take the first user input and skipps to the next line so for example I want to write "start" but what appears is:

"->

tart"

This is the "Engine" file that I import into the main script

```
import os
import time
import random
import winsound
import sys

running = True

start_loop = True

#Time
epoch_seconds = time.time()
localtime = time.localtime(epoch_seconds)
localdate = str(localtime.tm_mday)+"."+str(localtime.tm_mon)+"."+str(localtime.tm_year)

#random number
r = 0

# 0 : Has not started yet
stage = 0

inventory = []

storyline = ""

hp = 100

rations = 20


#Input Template
unconditionalinputs = ["hilfe","menu","antwortmöglichkeiten","inventar","rationen"]

playerinput = ""


#Startup
def startup_sequence():
    while True:
        logo()
        load()
        print("---------------")
        print("START")
        print("---------------")
        print("CREDITS")
        print("---------------")
        print("HILFE")
        print("---------------")
        
        startinput = input("-> ")

        if startinput.lower() != "start" and startinput.lower() != "credits" and startinput.lower() != "hilfe":
            os.system("cls")
            print("Es gibt nur Start, Credits und Hilfe.")

        if startinput.lower() == "start":
            os.system("cls")
            time.sleep(1)
            break
            
        if startinput.lower() == "credits":
            os.system("cls")
            credits()

        if startinput.lower() == "hilfe":
            os.system("cls")
            help()
            input()
            os.system("cls")
    


def logo():
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n                                                                                       ▄▄        \n▀████▀     █     ▀███▀                                ▀███▀▀▀███                  ██  ███        \n  ▀██     ▄██     ▄█                                    ██    ▀█                  ██   ██        \n   ██▄   ▄███▄   ▄█   ▄█▀██▄ ▀███▄███▀████████▄█████▄   ██   █   ▄█▀██▄ ▀███▄█████████ ███████▄  \n    ██▄  █▀ ██▄  █▀  ██   ██   ██▀ ▀▀  ██    ██    ██   ██████  ██   ██   ██▀ ▀▀  ██   ██    ██  \n    ▀██ █▀  ▀██ █▀    ▄█████   ██      ██    ██    ██   ██   █  ▄▄█████   ██      ██   ██    ██  \n     ▄██▄    ▄██▄    ██   ██   ██      ██    ██    ██   ██     ▄██   ██   ██      ██   ██    ██  \n      ██      ██     ▀████▀██▄████▄  ▄████  ████  ████▄██████████████▀██▄████▄    ▀███████  ████▄\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")


def credits():
    print("-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("Programmierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("----------------------------\nProgrammierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("Design/Storyline: Paul | Bajak | Rolo\n----------------------------\nProgrammierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("----------------------------\nDesign/Storyline: Paul | Bajak | Rolo\n----------------------------\nProgrammierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("Charakter Design: Paul | Bajak\n----------------------------\nDesign/Storyline: Paul | Bajak | Rolo\n----------------------------\nProgrammierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("-----------------------------------\nCharakter Design: Paul | Bajak\n----------------------------\nDesign/Storyline: Paul | Bajak | Rolo\n----------------------------\nProgrammierung: Lynndog\n-----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("")
    input()
    os.system("cls")

def help():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print_slow("-----------------------------------\n-Nach jeder Aktion (ausgenommen Frageunspezifische Eingabemöglichkeiten) wird eine Ration verbraucht\n\n-Die Fragespezifischen Eingabemöglichkeiten können mit -Antwortmöglichkeiten abgerufen werden\n-Wenn das Spiel stoppt kann man meißtens mit Enter weiter\n-Andere Eingabemöglichkeiten sind:\n   -Inventar (um sein Inventar anzuzeigen)\n   -Rationen (zeigt die verbleibenden Rationen)\n   -Hilfe (um dieses Menü aufzurufen)\n   -Menu (Zurück ins Menü, ACHTUNG SPEICHERT NICHT NOCHMAL EXTRA)\n-----------------------------------",0.001)
    print("")


#Add to Inventory if not already there
def add_to_inventory(item):
    if item not in inventory:
        inventory.append(item)
    else:
        inventory
        print_slow("->Du hast bereits: "+str(item),0.1)  

def show_inventory():
    print(*inventory, sep=", ")

def clear_inventory():
    inventory=[]

#Add or remove rations
def add_rations(added_rations):
    global rations
    rations += added_rations
    print_slow("->Du hast "+str(added_rations)+" Ration/en erhalten!",0.1)

def remove_rations(removed_rations):
    global rations
    rations -= removed_rations
    print_slow("->Du hast "+str(removed_rations)+" Ration/en verloren!",0.1)

#Add or remove hp
def add_hp(added_hp):
    global hp
    if hp + added_hp <= 100:
        hp+=added_hp
    else:
        hp=100

def remove_hp(removed_hp):
    global hp
    if hp - removed_hp <= 0:
        die()
    else:
        hp-=removed_hp


#Die
def die():
    print("                            ▄▄         ▄▄                                                                  ▄▄                           \n▀███▀▀▀██▄                 ▄██         ██          ██                               ██                    ▄██                           \n  ██    ▀██▄                ██                     ██                               ██                     ██                           \n  ██     ▀█████  ▀███       ██▄████▄ ▀███  ▄██▀████████     ▄█▀█████ ▄▄█▀██ ▄██▀████████  ▄██▀██▄▀███▄███  ██▄████▄   ▄▄█▀██▀████████▄  \n  ██      ██ ██    ██       ██    ▀██  ██  ██   ▀▀ ██      ▄██  ██  ▄█▀   ████   ▀▀ ██   ██▀   ▀██ ██▀ ▀▀  ██    ▀██ ▄█▀   ██ ██    ██  \n  ██     ▄██ ██    ██       ██     ██  ██  ▀█████▄ ██      ▀█████▀  ██▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█████▄ ██   ██     ██ ██      ██     ██ ██▀▀▀▀▀▀ ██    ██  \n  ██    ▄██▀ ██    ██       ██▄   ▄██  ██  █▄   ██ ██      ██       ██▄    ▄█▄   ██ ██   ██▄   ▄██ ██      ██▄   ▄██ ██▄    ▄ ██    ██  \n▄████████▀   ▀████▀███▄     █▀█████▀ ▄████▄██████▀ ▀████    ███████  ▀█████▀██████▀ ▀████ ▀█████▀▄████▄    █▀█████▀   ▀█████▀████  ████▄\n                                                           █▀     ██                                                                                                                               ██████▀                                                                      \n")
    input()
    startup_sequence()


#Add to storyline
def add_to_storyline(storyline_text):
    global localdate
    global storyline
    storyline = storyline+"\n"+(str(localdate)+"\n"+storyline_text)


#Sounds
def play_sound(soundfile):
    try:
        winsound.play_sound("sounds/"+soundfile)
    except:
        pass


def print_slow(str,timebetweenchars):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end ='', flush = True)
        time.sleep(timebetweenchars)
    print("")


#Check for the not Question-specific inputs
def inputcheck(inputmessage,otherinputslist2):
    inputmessage = inputmessage.lower()
    if inputmessage == "hilfe":
        help()
    if inputmessage == "menu":
        running = False
        os.system("cls")
    if inputmessage == "antwortmöglichkeiten":
        print(*otherinputslist2, sep=", ")
    if inputmessage == "inventar":
        show_inventory()
    if inputmessage == "rationen":
        print_slow("Du hast noch "+str(rations)+" Rationen",0.1)

def inputtemplate(otherinputslist):
    global playerinput
    global rations

    playerinput = ""
    while playerinput not in otherinputslist:
        playerinput = input(": ")
        inputcheck(playerinput,otherinputslist)
        while playerinput.lower() not in unconditionalinputs and playerinput.lower() not in otherinputslist:
            print_slow("Diese Eingabemöglichkeit gibt es nicht!",0.1)
            playerinput = input(": ")
            inputcheck(playerinput,otherinputslist)
    if playerinput in otherinputslist:
        if rations == 0:
            print_slow("Du hast keine Rationen mehr. -1HP",0.1)
            print_slow("-> Du hast noch "+ str(hp)+"HP",0.1)
        if rations > 0:
            rations -= 1
    

#Saving and Loading
def make_save_dirs():
    if not os.path.exists("save_files"):
        os.makedirs("save_files")

    if not os.path.exists("sounds"):
        print_slow("Sound Files Missing!",0.1)

    if not os.path.exists("save_files/stage.txt"):
        f = open("save_files/stage.txt", "w")
        f.write(str(stage))
        f.close()
    
    if not os.path.exists("save_files/inventory.txt"):
        f = open("save_files/inventory.txt", "w")
        f.close()

    if not os.path.exists("save_files/storyline.txt"):
        f = open("save_files/storyline.txt", "w")
        f.close()

    if not os.path.exists("save_files/hp.txt"):
        f = open("save_files/hp.txt", "w")
        f.write(str(hp))
        f.close()

    if not os.path.exists("save_files/rations.txt"):
        f = open("save_files/rations.txt", "w")
        f.write(str(rations))
        f.close()


#Saving and Loadign the Inventory
def save_inventory():
    f = open("save_files/inventory.txt", "w+")
    for item in inventory:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
    f.close()

def load_inventory():
    f = open("save_files/inventory.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        x = line[:-1]
        inventory.append(x)
    f.close()


#Saving Any Int, Str etc.
def save_anything(save_file_name, variable):
    f = open("save_files/"+save_file_name, "w+")
    f.write(str(variable))
    f.close

#Load Int
def load_int(save_file_name):
    f = open("save_files/"+save_file_name, "r")
    variable = int(f.read())
    return variable
    f.close()

#Load Str
def load_str(save_file_name):
    f = open("save_files/"+save_file_name, "r")
    variable = f.read()
    return variable
    f.close()


def save():
    make_save_dirs()
    save_inventory()
    save_anything("stage.txt", stage)
    save_anything("storyline.txt", storyline)
    save_anything("hp.txt", hp)
    save_anything("rations.txt", rations)

    print("---------------")
    print_slow("--> Spiel wurde gespeichert",0.1)
    print("---------------")

def load():
    global stage
    global storyline
    global hp
    global rations
    make_save_dirs()
    load_inventory()
    stage = load_int("stage.txt")
    hp = load_int("hp.txt")
    storyline = load_str("storyline.txt")
    rations = load_int("rations.txt")
```

And this is the main script

```
import quest_engine as qe
from quest_engine import *


#Time
epoch_seconds = time.time()
localtime = time.localtime(epoch_seconds)
localdate = str(localtime.tm_mday)+"."+str(localtime.tm_mon)+"."+str(localtime.tm_year)
year = localtime.tm_year
game_year = year+100



while qe.running:
    os.system("cls")

    startup_sequence()

    # 0 TUTORIAL
    # 1 BRENNENDES AUTO
    # 2 IN DER SCHULE

    if qe.stage == 0:
        add_to_storyline("Tagebuch gefunden.")
        print_slow("02.10."+str(game_year)+"\nIch habe heute aus dem Fenster geschaut.\nIch denke oft über die Zukunft nach in letzter Zeit.\nSie macht mir Sorgen,\nSie macht mir Angst.\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("15.03."+str(game_year+16)+"\nEs ist soweit.\nZum Glück konnte ich noch mein Tagebuch greifen.\nEs gibt keinen Strom mehr, nurnoch wenig Nahrung.\nJeder Tropfen Benzin ist leer.\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("21.10."+str(game_year+33)+"\nMein Gott ich habe die Lösung gefunden!\nDamit können wir den Planeten kühlen!\nIch bringe diesen Plan zur alten Schule.\nDort werden wir ihn in die Tat umsetzen!\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du: Oh schau mal!\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Was ist das?\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Oh Interessant.\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du: Schule..\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du: Kennst du eine Schule hier in der nähe?\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Naja im Norden ist glaub ich eine. Aber ich bin mir nicht sicher.\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du: Wer weiß, aber wenn wir Glück haben hat der Typ vom Tagebuch was dort gelassen.\n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Ja lass uns hingehen!\n",0.01)
        add_to_storyline("Auf den Weg zur Schule.")
        add_to_inventory("Tagebuch")
        input()
        os.system("cls")
        qe.stage = 1
        save()

    if qe.stage == 1:
        print("---------------")
        print_slow("TEIL 1: Auf der suche nach dem Wissenschaftler",0.01)
        print("\n---------------")
        print_slow("Du triffst auf ein brennendes Auto.",0.01)
        print_slow("\n                            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@%                                     \n                    .@@            @@@         @@@                              \n                @@@                 @@               @@                         \n              @@                    @@                  @@@                     \n          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#       \n  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  \n @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@ (@@@@@@@@ \n.@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@      /@@@ @@@@@@@\n @@@@@@@@@@@ @@          @@&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@         @@@/@@@@@@\n         (@@ @@          @@%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@         @@@@@@@@@ \n              @@@      &@@@                                @@@       @@@        \n                @@@@@@@@                                     @@@@@@@@@          \n                                                                                \n",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du hörst schreihe aus dem Auto hervorkommen!",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Möchtest du dem Gefangenen helfen?",0.01)
        
        inputtemplate(["ja","nein"])
        if qe.playerinput == "ja":
            qe.r = random.randint(1,100)
            #Branndwunde
            if qe.r <= 33:
                qe.hp -= random.randint(5,8)
                add_to_storyline("Du bekommst Schaden beim retten einer Person in einem brennenden Auto. Du hast noch"+ str(qe.hp)+"HP.")
                print_slow("Leider bekommst du Schaden beim retten der Person und hast nur noch "+str(qe.hp)+"HP",0.01)
                input()


            #Keine Wunden
            if qe.r > 33:
                add_to_storyline("Du rettest eine Person aus einem brennenden Auto.")
                print_slow("Du hast Glück und bekommst keinen Schaden beim retten der Person.",0.01)
                input()

            print_slow("Person: Oh Gott.. *hust*",0.01)
            input()
            print_slow("Person: Wie kann ich dir danken? *hust*",0.01)
            input()
            if qe.r > 33:
                print_slow("Person: Zum Glück bist du unversehrt! Hier.. nimm ein Paar meiner Rationen zum Dank!",0.01)
                add_rations((random.randint(2,4)))

            if qe.r <= 33:
                print_slow("Person: Oje. Es tut mir leid das ich dich da reingezogen habe. Hier.. nimm ein Paar meiner Rationen zum Dank!",0.01)
                add_rations((random.randint(4,7)))
            input()
            print_slow("Du bedankst dich bei ihm und gehst weiter richtung Schule.",0.01)

        if qe.playerinput == "nein":
            print_slow("Du ignorierst die schrecklichen Schreihe und gehst entschlossen weiter!",0.01)
            
        input()
        qe.stage = 2
        save()

    if qe.stage == 2:
        print_slow("?: Hey schau mal!",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Dort hinten ist die Schule.",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Ihr nähert euch der Eingangstür.",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("Du: Okay. Bevor wir dort jetzt reingehen, will ich noch wissen wer du bist. Wer weiß was da drinn passiert",0.01)
        input()
        print_slow("?: Nagut ich sage es dir",0.01)
```

I don't know if it's important, but I start the main file throught a batch file like that:

```
@echo off
start /b "WarmEarth" python "warmearth.py"
pause
```

Comment: It's OK not to want to include your full program - in fact, it's appreciated if you reduce the code to just what is needed to reproduce the issue. However, the code you shared doesn't have the problem you describe, and cannot be run to demonstrate the problem. If you add a call to `startup_sequence()` (and remove the calls to `logo()` and `load()`, you'll find that the problem you described doesn't appear.

Comment: I included more code now. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It shows a bit more, but after running it, it still doesn't show the behaviour you mentioned. It seems to work as intended (after removing some references that weren't included, and commenting out the directory and file creation). You'll have to be more specific about how you run this script / program and what exactly the behaviour is that is causing you trouble.

Comment: I can include the whole code of both scripts if you want but I thought that would make it to complicated to read and understand.

Comment: Yes so I added both files now. I will just work on the game and let this bug there until someone has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a cmd bug. It works when I open the program without the batch file but through the consol.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine (tested locally)

```
def logo():
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n                                                                                       ▄▄        \n▀████▀     █     ▀███▀                                ▀███▀▀▀███                  ██  ███        \n  ▀██     ▄██     ▄█                                    ██    ▀█                  ██   ██        \n   ██▄   ▄███▄   ▄█   ▄█▀██▄ ▀███▄███▀████████▄█████▄   ██   █   ▄█▀██▄ ▀███▄█████████ ███████▄  \n    ██▄  █▀ ██▄  █▀  ██   ██   ██▀ ▀▀  ██    ██    ██   ██████  ██   ██   ██▀ ▀▀  ██   ██    ██  \n    ▀██ █▀  ▀██ █▀    ▄█████   ██      ██    ██    ██   ██   █  ▄▄█████   ██      ██   ██    ██  \n     ▄██▄    ▄██▄    ██   ██   ██      ██    ██    ██   ██     ▄██   ██   ██      ██   ██    ██  \n      ██      ██     ▀████▀██▄████▄  ▄████  ████  ████▄██████████████▀██▄████▄    ▀███████  ████▄\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")

def startup_sequence():
    while True:
        logo()
        # load()
        print("---------------")
        print("START")
        print("---------------")
        print("CREDITS")
        print("---------------")
        print("HELP")
        print("---------------")
        
        startinput = input("-> ")
        print(startinput)

startup_sequence()
```

The only thing that can mess something up is load function, which is not included in the question description

Comment: Your answer isn't really answering the question (or rather, as pointed out in the comments, OP's code is missing the problem they are having). That's best left in a comment, since an answer should provide an answer. (or you can vote that the problem cannot be reproduced, if you feel OP won't / can't update the question to show the problem)